# VB.NET QR-Code Reader

Tags: vb.net, desktop, qr-code

I've easily found various QR-Code generators, but I need to use the data stored in the barcode on a regular desktop app using VB.Net and a WebCam or eventually an flash, javascript webpage to do the job.

Is that possible? Any products or tutorials avaiable?

Should there be an online service for this? Maybe a flash app?

Need some directions...

Thx
Paulo Bueno.

Answer (score 1):

Open Source library:  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx

Paid library: http://www.onbarcode.com/products/net_barcode_reader/barcodes/qrcode.html

There are likely more available as well.

Comment: Well I've done alot of testing on Qr-Codes but it seems there's no decent algorithm for desktop as there is in mobile. I've found different issues such as file size (resolution) and other factors but none seems to be effective to read the codes. I've tested the same images on mobile and they work fine. So, by now, i'm discating this feature in my project.